# Drools 7 - Reasoning over events associated with inferred facts

Tags: drools, fusion

We are working on a resource reservation system where we will get requests to book a resource for any arbitrary time (ranging from 5 mins - 2 hours). There are no predefined slots.

We trying to use Drools (Fusion) ver. 7.12.0.Final, to write the rules that will ensure that new booking requests do not override existing request that have been confirmed.

To achieve the above we have created the following 2 objects :

```
declare ReservationRequest
    @role ( event )
    @duration (reservationDuration )
    @timestamp ( pickupTime )

    id                  : int
    pickupTime          : Date
    reservationDuration : long   
    reserved            : String
    deliveryEnd     : Date
end
```

And

```
declare Reservation
    reservation             : ReservationRequest
end
```

'ReservationRequest' are being treated as events so that we can use temporal operators to evaluate new requests do not overlap  confirmed requests (captured as an inferred 'Reservation' fact.

We have written the following rule to check for the overlap and insert the corresponding 'Reservation' fact:

```
rule "Ensure no overlaped reservations using inferred facts"
    enabled true

    when
        reservationRequest : ReservationRequest( )
        not Reservation ( reservation == reservationRequest )
        reservations : Reservation() 
        not ReservationRequest( this overlaps reservations.reservation )
        not ReservationRequest( this overlappedby reservations.reservation  )
        not ReservationRequest( this includes reservations.reservation  )
    then
        insert( new Reservation ( reservationRequest ) );
 end
```

Unfortunately the above rule fails to run if there is a 'Reservation' fact in WM. I get the following error :

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Conversion to long not supported from com.sample.ReservationRequest
    at org.drools.core.base.extractors.BaseObjectClassFieldReader.getLongValue(BaseObjectClassFieldReader.java:133)
    at org.drools.core.base.ClassFieldReader.getLongValue(ClassFieldReader.java:198)
    at org.drools.core.rule.VariableRestriction$TemporalVariableContextEntry.updateFromTuple(VariableRestriction.java:641)
    at org.drools.core.common.SingleBetaConstraints.updateFromTuple(SingleBetaConstraints.java:116)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakNotNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakNotNode.java:108)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakNotNode.doNode(PhreakNotNode.java:85)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.switchOnDoBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:571)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:552)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:379)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:339)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:175)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:133)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:212)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:87)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1067)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1014)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1006)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1337)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1328)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1312)
    at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:24)
```

We have used inferred facts extensively in other scenarios, but this is the first time we're using it with events. So we're not sure if this is capability (inferring facts based on correlated events) is supported.

If this is not supported, what's the best way to 'save' events that are required while allowing other events to be evicted / retracted from WM. We could use 'flags' to mark the events we want to keep, but we would like to avoid that approach if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As much I am a Drools fan why don't you just create a SQL table with start_datetime and end_datetime together with "before insert on" trigger that checks that the inserted value doesn't overlap any of the existing (confirmed) values in DB. If the trigger throws exception during the insert then you catch it and you know that an overlap exists.

Comment: If our requirement were that simple, I would have done that. But we have to do additional reasoning on the new reservation requests before we can confirm the reservation. Down the road we will also have to reason over which resource best fits the reservation request and then allocate that resources time to this request - for that we are looking to implement optaplanner. That's why we're trying to see if we can leverage Drools from the get go so that we can incorporate this reasoning logic into our solver later.

Comment: Clear. I added a separate answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding $-sign in front of variable names then you can better distinct between fields and variables.

If you add a method `boolean isOverlap(ReservationRequest)` into the `ReservationRequest` class then you could write something like this:

```
when
    $reservationRequest : ReservationRequest( )
    not Reservation ( this.reservation.isOverlap($reservationRequest) )
then
    insert( new Reservation ( $reservationRequest ) );
```

This should be sufficient. I also highly recommend to use variable name "reservationRequest" when you refer to ReservationRequest right now it is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Master Drools. I do need one clarification though - Does this definition of Reservation not add the 'reservation' field :declare Reservation
    reservation             : ReservationRequest
end

Comment: Oops. It does. It is a terrible idea to have two classes - Reservation and ReservationRequest and then use field name "reservation" to refer to an object of type ReservationRequest. That got me confused. I edited my response to fix this.